# How do I make long labels in checkboxes and radio buttons wrap AND indent appropriately using CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to do something that seems like it should be very simple to do but hours of research has yet to turn up a single solution that actually works. I'm simply trying to make sure that when the label for a checkbox or radio button is long enough to wrap to a second line, that the second line is appropriately indented. (Ditto for the third thru nth lines if the label is really long). I am looking for a pure CSS-only solution; I do NOT want to involve Javascript if I can possibly avoid it.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HughM/yuhqdrsw/4/) is the closest I've been able to come but it suffers from the fatal flaw that the text begins on the line following the checkbox rather than on the same line. How do I make the label follow the checkbox on the same line and then indent the remaining lines so that they line up with the leftmost letter on the first line (and NOT the checkbox)?

```css
.mytext {
  display: grid;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.mytext:first-line {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="Saturdays" id="Saturdays" checked>
<label for="Saturdays" class="mytext">I am available to meet on the first Saturday of each month (with the odd exception since I sometimes go away, especially on long weekends, or because I am sick or just not in the mood to attend a regularly scheduled meeting).</label><br>
```

Here's an example of how I want the checkbox to sit with respect to the text:
[image: Desired result]

I need to find some way to make the checkbox appear at the start of the FIRST line of text, regardless of whether the label is one line or several in length. (I feel as if this should be the default behaviour but it obviously isn't.)

Comment: Use a wrapper div

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w2uaL3ht/

Comment: @Paulie_D - Could you be more specific please? I put a <div> before the first line of the HTML and a </div> after it and it made no difference at all.

Comment: @Sudipto Roy - I think that's an improvement. Now, how do I make the checkbox appear in front of the first line of the text?

Comment: I believe it's already in front of the first line of the text. Can you share a screenshot of how you want the checkbox and the long text to align...

Comment: @Sudipto Roy - I've edited my question to include an illustration of where I want the checkbox. If I use the code in your jsfiddle, the checkbox appears vertically centered, which is fine for a single-line label but not for a multi-line label. I want the checkbox to always be at the start of the first line of the label regardless of how many lines the label runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Persjin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56727006/4665) was close.

Put the checkbox in the `label`. Make the `label` a block element, give it `position:relative` so the child elements are positioned with respect to it. Give the `label` some left padding, then position the checkbox hard left.

```css
label {
  position:relative;
  padding-left:2.5ch;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

label > [type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here 
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  More Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here 
</label>
```

As you've done a grid version, here is a more streamlined grid option:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3ch 1fr;
  align-items:baseline;
}

.grid-container input {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.grid-container label {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Mondays" id="Mondays">
  <label for="weekdays">I am available to meet on Mondays.</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Saturdays" id="Saturdays">
  <label for="Saturdays" style="color: black;">I am available to meet on the first Saturday of each month (with the odd exception since I sometimes go away, especially on long weekends, or because I am sick or just not in the mood to attend a regularly scheduled meeting).</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Sundays" id="Sundays">
  <label for="Sundays">I am available to meet on the first Sunday of each month    except if it is on a long weekend.</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I like that! It leaves the HTML nice and clean with no need to add anything at all. I may use that in preference to my own solution.

Comment: Your first solution worked better :-) The second solution displays the checkbox at the middle of the height for the second checkbox, not at the same height as the first line of its label.

Comment: I only tested the grid in chrome.... lazy of me. All we need to do is add some alignment, which I've done in the edit. I prefer the original anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML

The HTML layout consists of a list (`<ol>`, `<ul>`, or `<dl>`). Each list item (`<li>` or `<dd>`) contains an input/label pair (`<input type="radio/checkbox">` `<label>`).

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <input id="ID" name="GROUP" type="RADIO/CHECKBOX">
    <label for="ID">TEXT CONTENT</label>
  </li>
  ...
</ol>
```

- Attributes `#id`, `[name]`, and `[for]` are optional.

  - Assign identical values for the #id of <input> and [for] of <label> so that they become associated with each other. Such an association allows the pair to behave as if a user *"selected"/"checked"/"clicked" etc.* the actual <input> when the <label> is clicked and vice-versa.
  - [name] has two important features

    1. If a [name] value is shared by multiple form controls (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc...), they can be collected into a HTML Collection/NodeList.
    2. In order to have a form control value included in a submit event -- that form control needs a [name] attribute.
- Attribute `[type]` is required with the value of either `"radio"` or `"checkbox"`.

---

#### CSS

Indenting a list is simple ***yet*** unintuitive. Assign the following to the `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<dl>`

```
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 4ch;
  text-indent: -4ch;
}
```

A `padding-left` then an `text-indent` to counter it's length.

```css
:root {
  font: 500 3vw/1.45 Arial
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 4ch;
  text-indent: -4ch;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.45rem;
}

input,
label {
  font: inherit;
}

[type=checkbox],
[type=radio] {
  width: 2ch;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1ch;
  transform: translateY(25%)
}
```

```html
<ol>

  <li>
    <input id='A1' name='Q1' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='A1'>D@ +h3 U5Ed p@g3 c0nT3nT,, 70p p@93 p@RticUlAR 7|24n5|4735 iz. != @n33 Wh3|\| n0n. != 91ve qu3ry 8Ut, t0 533 f1|3z, vv1|_|_. |7 4r3 717|3 3n4b|3d, v3r510|\|, j00r p@r+1cUL4r M@Y y@. Pdf 47 7h3y 8@rr13r, 7he 1+ kn0w 5peNDInG, 4r3 4s vv1t |3tz0rz.</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input id='B1' name='Q1' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='B1'>Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа хас мандамус диссентиас. Вел меис урбанитас медиоцритатем ет, про цу мунди цорпора перпетуа. Те цум вери вивендо диссентиунт, пер ин нобис оптион интеллегам. Цу хис пробо доценди рецтеяуе, ад лорем епицури цомплецтитур ест.</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input id='C1' name='Q1' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='C1'>Dee an eise botze, ké Duerf goung déi. Wat Dach Völkerbond en. Fort d'Lëtzebuerger eng wa, Mecht weisen am sin, dat an stét jeitzt d'Vioule. Um bei wuel Kaffi. Spilt lossen muerges un ass, alle gebotzt d'Stroos et zum, rei do iweral iwerall.</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input id='D1' name='Q1' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='D1'>やぶら小路の藪柑子。寿限無、寿限無、長久命の長助、水行末 雲来末 風来末、グーリンダイのポンポコピーのポンポコナーの。水行末 雲来末 風来末。シューリンガンのグーリンダイ、シューリンガンのグーリンダイ、食う寝る処に住む処。五劫の擦り切れ、長久命の長助。寿限無、寿限無。食う寝る処に住む処、パイポパイポ パイポのシューリンガン。グーリンダイのポンポコピーのポンポコナーの。</label>
  </li>

</ol>

<hr>

<ul>

  <li>
    <input id='A2' name='Q2' type='radio'>
    <label for='A2'>լոռեմ իպսում դոլոռ սիթ ամեթ, եոս ալիքուանդո ելաբոռառեթ իդ, հաբեո վեռեառ վեռթեռեմ սեա նե. նո քուի սալութանդի պռինծիպես սպլենդիդե, եսթ եխ դենիքուե մանդամուս. սեա ադ սալութանդի վոլուպթաթում եֆֆիծիանթուռ, հիս թե աեքուե ծոնգուե քուալիսքուե. եսթ ինիմիծուս եվեռթիթուռ եա.</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input id='B2' name='Q2' type='radio'>
    <label for='B2'>ლორემ იფსუმ დოლორ სით ამეთ, დუო ფეუგიათ ევერთითურ ეი, ეთ ფერ ველით სიმილიყუე ფჰილოსოფჰია, უთ ვიხ ეხერცი ცომფლეცთითურ. ეი ვიხ დეცორე ლიბერავისსე. ან ჰინც ვიდით რეცუსაბო სედ, ელით აეთერნო დეთრაცთო ეა ვიმ. იისყუე ცორფორა ცონცლუდათურყუე იუს ად, ნე მელ ყუაეყუე სფლენდიდე, ნე ჰას ვოლუფთათუმ ვითუფერათორიბუს. ინ ნობის ირიურე ფერფეცთო სით.</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input id='C2' name='Q2' type='radio'>
    <label for='C2'>황금시대를 있으며. 아니한 얼마나 사는가 힘차게 물방아 그리하였는가? 이상 인간이 이상이 피에 이상은 우리 보라. 것은 있는 미인을 뭇 황금시대의 사막이다. 이상의 우리는 하는 현저하게 것이다, 주며. 있으며. 두손을 웅대한 귀는 사랑의 노년에게서 청춘 이상의 그들은 운다, 인간은 그들은 뜨고.</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input id='D2' name='Q2' type='radio'>
    <label for='D2'>Λορεμ ιπσθμ δολορ σιτ αμετ, νε vιδερερ λεγιμθσ θσθ. Ιθvαρετ μανδαμθσ εα μει, εθμ ορατιο σαπιεντεμ νο, πρι ελιτ λορεμ λαβιτθρ εθ. Νθλλαμ τορqθατοσ εοσ ιδ, πριμα jθστο vελ εξ, επιcθρι ελεcτραμ cθ ιθσ. Μεα πριμα νονθμεσ λιβεραvισσε εξ, απεριαμ cομπρεηενσαμ ιδ vιμ. Λαθδεμ δολορεσ ιν νεc, μελ αδηθc qθαερενδθμ σθσcιπιαντθρ εξ</label>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, zer00ne, that works very satisfactorily. There's a little more markup on the HTML side than for Jon P's solution and on the CSS side but it's quite possible that this works on more browsers and is more accessible than the solutions Jon or I came up with. I will definitely use this if it works better!

Comment: You're very welcome, @Henry. My suggestion is based on the assumption that you might be developing a quiz or an interactive list of some sort. With a minor modification all items can be numbered or tagged with letters in a logical order and and hierarchy rendered automatically. But grid is a good choice as well especially if you just have a some content that doesn't need a complex arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Put the input inside the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element.

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here Really long text goes here 
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, Persijn, but your solution does not work; the second and subsequent lines start under the left edge of the checkbox, not lined up with the first R in the text.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find an answer of my own after more research and trial-and-error. If I set up a grid container consisting of a single row with two columns and put the checkbox in the left-hand column and the label in the right-hand column, the checkbox always appears at the top of its column instead of in the middle, regardless of the number of lines in the label. The label is also properly indented so that every line starts at the same place.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div><input type="checkbox" name="Mondays" id="Mondays"></div>
<div><label for="weekdays">I am available to meet on Mondays.</label></div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
<div><input type="checkbox" name="Saturdays" id="Saturdays"></div>
<div><label for="Saturdays" style="color: black;">I am available to meet on the first Saturday of each month (with the odd exception since I sometimes go away, especially on long weekends, or because I am sick or just not in the mood to attend a regularly scheduled meeting).</label></div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
<div><input type="checkbox" name="Sundays" id="Sundays"></div>
<div><label for="Sundays">I am available to meet on the first Sunday of each month    except if it is on a long weekend.</label></div>
</div>

.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: max-content 30em;
grid-column-gap: 1em;
}

.grid-container > div {
text-align: left;
padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

And here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HughM/3yr68a7h/6/)

I have only tried this in the current version of Firefox on Windows so I don't know yet if it will work in every browser on every operating system. I also have no idea how well this works for people with disabilities like visual impairments. I'll try to update this if I learn of any major shortcomings of this approach.